# How would this nonchord tone be labeled? Is it a retardation?

Tags: theory, analysis, nonchord-tones

[image]

I'm working on an analysis of a song, and there is a section where the phrase starts off on this E-natural note over a B-flat major triad. This is the first note of the melody line.

Since it isn't approached by anything, would it make sense to call this a 4-5 retardation? Is it better to call it a free tone?

I know nonchord tone criteria doesn't always work, but I wanted to see if there is a good way to label this note. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks to me like a blue note - flat 5. So, a chromatic approach to the P5. Retardation is usually what is called sus2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an accented lower neighbor.